# Hot to do subset in R with aggregation?

Tags: r, subset

I have a large data frame (200000 rows) with 2 columns: group_id and user_id. One user can belong to multiple groups. I need a result dataframe with group_id, user_id of all users who belong to more than 3 groups.

```
group_id  user_id
100       1
101       1
102       1
103       1
101       2
103       2
```

In the above example, in the resultant data frame I will get the first 4 rows only.

```
df <- structure(list(group_id = c(100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 103L
    ), user_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("group_id", 
    "user_id"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "data.table" package makes this simple.  If `df` is the original data frame, you can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[.N > 3], by = user_id]
#    user_id group_id
# 1:       1      100
# 2:       1      101
# 3:       1      102
# 4:       1      103
```

`.N` tells us how many rows are in each group (here chosen to be `user_id`), and `.SD` selects all columns.  So `.SD[.N > 3]` gives us all groups that have more than three rows.

Note:  If you don't want to change the original `df` to a data table, you can use `as.data.table()` in place of `setDT()`.  However, this will make a copy of `df`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a **dplyr** solution but in seeing @Richard's I know there's a better **dplyr** way too:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    count(user_id) %>%
    filter(n > 3) %>%
    select(user_id) %>%
    inner_join(df, .)

## Joining by: "user_id"
##   group_id user_id
## 1      100       1
## 2      101       1
## 3      102       1
## 4      103       1
```

Using @Richard's comment:

```
df %>%
    group_by(user_id) %>% 
    filter(n() > 3)
```

Comment: I think an easier dplyr way would be `group_by(df, user_id) %>% slice(n() > 3)`

Comment: @RichardScriven perfect

Comment: @Richard I think the `slice` doesn't work but `filter` does (see my edit)

Comment: Right.  My fault.  That should be `filter()`.  I thought `slice()` was also doing that now but I was mistaken

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that 'group_id' is unique per each 'user_id', an option using `base R` would be

```
 df[with(df, ave(user_id, user_id, FUN=length)>3),]
 #     group_id user_id
 #1      100       1
 #2      101       1
 #3      102       1
 #4      103       1
```